# EmberJS RESTAdapter - Specific url for

Tags: ember.js

I have a Host model on ember-data:

```
App.Host = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
```

And I using the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

EmberJS calls `/hosts` to get hosts which is normal.

My problem is the url to get hosts is not `/hosts` but `/nagios/hosts`.

How can I specify this url only for Host model?

I already tried those answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956243/1731473
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16453742/1731473
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566425/1731473

Without any success.

Currently using:

```
Ember      : 1.10.0
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.15
jQuery     : 2.0.3
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the correct solution.

For begin by the context, I have an initial RESTAdapter config:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  host: 'http://localhost:8000/api'
```

To add the `/nagios` url part, just create a file named `adapters/host.coffee` (or .js) like this:

```
App.HostAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend
  namespace: 'nagios'
```

Please not `App.ApplicationAdapter` extension instead of `DS.RESTAdapter` in order to keep the initial configuration.

And voila! The called url is now `http://localhost:8000/api/nagios/hosts`.

Thanks a lot to [EntspAndi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4576905/entspandi) for the very useful help!

Answer (score 3):

Add an adapter (ember generate adapter hosts) just for the hosts model and add the namespace property:

```
App.HostsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'nagios'
});
```

Comment: Where should I put this by convention? On my model file?

Comment: If you are using Ember CLI you could use the ember generator like: ember generate adapter hosts and it will generate a folder called "hosts.js" in "adapters". So the full path is .../app/adapters/hosts.js

Comment: I'm not using Ember CLI. I tested your solution, did nothing. What could I did wrong?

Comment: You could try to name it: App.HostAdapter instead of App.HostsAdapter, but make sure that this code is somewhere included or create an own file like hosts-adapter.js and include it.

Comment: Here are the docs for further reading: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/
It is definitely possible to create an adapter for a single model by just following the naming conventions.

Comment: Works with App.HostAdapter indeed! But the namespace option override completely my 'api' main namespace. Is there a where to retrieve and concat it with the host namespace? Thanks.

Comment: Found it. Will extend your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

namespace for setting a path in same directory

```
App.HostsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({namespace: 'nagios' });
```

Or

host generally is used for changing the directory

```
App.HostsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ host: 'nagios' });
```

In case you want to add suffix to the file name do it this way (place this inside extend()).

```
suffix: '.json',

      pathForType: function(type) {
        return this._super(type) + this.get('suffix');
      }
```